# jQuery zClip copy to clipboard, for multiple links in bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, clipboard-interaction

**If this cant be done for cross-browser, then any comments would be much appreciated.**

What I am trying to achieve is multiple "copy to clipboard" links on my page like this for example...

```
<a href="#" data-copy="<?php echo $original[0]; ?>" class="copy">Copy Original Link</a>
<a href="#" data-copy="<?php echo $medium[0]; ?>" class="copy">Copy Medium Link</a>
<a href="#" data-copy="<?php echo $web[0]; ?>" class="copy">Copy Web Link</a>
```

Just not really having much luck getting anything to work.

I am using [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/), and trying to fire using jQuery onClick and a data attribute, like below.

But just cannot get it to work. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/5/).

```
var copyText = 0;

$("a.copy").on('click', function () {

  var copyText = $(this).attr('data-copy');
  return false;

}).each(function () {

  $(this).zclip({

    path: 'http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: copyText,
    beforeCopy: function () {

    },
    afterCopy: function () {

      alert(copyText + " has been copied!");

    }

  });

});
```

Please see my new fiddle here with [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) jquery plugin being used.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/5/

Thank in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/180/) that does what you are trying to do:

Using this (the same) HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-copy="http://test.one.com/" class="copy">Copy Original Link</a>
<br />
<a href="#" data-copy="http://test.two.com/" class="copy">Copy Medium Link</a>
<br />
<a href="#" data-copy="http://test.three.com/" class="copy">Copy Web Link</a>
```

This script should work:

```
$("a.copy").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).each(function () {
  $(this).zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
      return $(this).data('copy');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is what I did.  First off the `alert` that you were adding via `afterCopy` is actually the default, so you don't need to add extra code for that.  Also the `data-copy` attributes should be accessed via jQuery's [`data` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).  Finally I put the SWF reference to the same host as the JavaScript (this might not be necessary depending on the 
security code in the SWF but it seemed necessary to get the jsfiddle to work.

Comment: Jason, thank you very much for your intuitive help. I have finally got simple links to work on my application. Thank you! However I have run into a small conflict with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) which may have been the cause of my many previous attempts and not having any results. All my copy to clip board links are in a bootstrap dropdown. I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/7/)  so you can see the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/7/

Do you think you could help me with this please? I can't seem to override the issue.

Comment: This demo is not available anymore. Any idea where I can see that demo working in entirety?

Comment: @EricB I updated the JSFiddle and bumped up the jQuery version (also I embedded the HTML so you could create this answer from scratch without access to the demo)

Comment: Actually this was the one I added: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/180/, but here is an updated version of your link: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/181/ (with Bootstrap 2.3.2 and updated jQuery)

Comment: This helped me and saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: Im not sure why, but this is not working on my browser. im using chrome and when i click on items, nothing happens. I've tried using the script on my app and does not work either nor in the fiddle. so weird.

Comment: @gapex I can't seem to get this to work in y copy of Firefox on Windows 7, I should dust off this answer and see if there is a new way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jason Sperske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16959/jason-sperske) solution, I have found a work around to fix the issue when used inside a bootstrap down.

This is how to get the function to work with bootstrap dropdowns.

```
$('.btn-group').addClass('open');
$("a.copy").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).each(function () {
  $(this).zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
      return $(this).data('copy');
    }
  });
});
$('.btn-group').removeClass('open');
```

Then this css also needs adding, to stop the flash file absolute div positioning outside of the list element.

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    position: relative;
}
```

See working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/27/